# 3n+1 Sequence Function with 'count'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def seq3np1(n):

    count = 0
    
    """ Print the 3n+1 sequence from n, terminating when it reaches 1."""

    while(n != 1):
        
        if(n % 2) == 0:        # n is even
            n = n // 2
            count += 1

        else:                 # n is odd
            n = n * 3 + 1
            count += 1
    return count



def main():

    num=int(input("what number do you want to put?: "))
    seq3np1(num)
    print("This is the starting number: ", num)
    print("Number of iterations:", count)
    
main()
```

This is a code I have for now, I have to do

> - seq3np1 function keeps track of and returns the count
> - asks user for an upper bound for the range value
> - uses the range (inclusively)
> - Has a drawing function that takes the number of iterations as a parameter
> - Graphs the results and updates world coordinates based on the largest value returned from seq3np1
> - Prints, on the graph, the max so far

But if I try to print 'count' on main function, it says count is undefined. What am I supposed to do to print count on main function?

Comment: define a variable `count` in main.  The only `count` variable you have currently is in `seq3np1`, which has it's own scope.  That function "returns" count, but you don't store it anywhere.  in main you should replace the function call with the line `count = seq3np1(num)`.  Note that this `count` is different from the one defined in the function.  You might even change the name for clarity: `numIterations =  seq3np1(num)` and `print("Number of iterations:", numIterations)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables defined in a function belong to that function `namespace`; they are not accessible outside of the `scope` of the function. (namespace and scope are words you should look up and learn about in the python documentation)

In `main`, you must assign the result returned by `seq3np1` to `count`

```
num=int(input("what number do you want to put?: "))
count = seq3np1(num)     # <--- Here
print("This is the starting number: ", num)
print("Number of iterations:", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

count is defined in the seqnp1 function and when that function exits, the count variable is no longer available then.

So , you can store the return value of seqnp1 funtion into a variable and then use it.

Modify the line in the **main** function :

*from*

```
seq3np1(num)
```

*to*

```
count = seq3np1(num)
```

and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

define a variable `count` in main, then
Store the return value from `seq3np1()` to that variable.

The only `count` variable you have currently is in `seq3np1`, which has it's own scope.
That function "returns" `count` to main, but you don't store it anywhere in main, so you have lost that return value.

**in main you should replace the function call**
`seq3np1(num)`
**with the line**
`count = seq3np1(num)`

Note that this new var, `count` in `main()`, would be distinct from `count` defined in the `seq3np1()` function.

You might even change the `count` variable name in main
so you can see how it's different from the `count` variable in `seq3np1()` by using the following in `main()` instead of the above fix:

`numIterations =  seq3np1(num)`
and then
`print("Number of iterations:", numIterations)`.